# Error while making conditional compilation

Tags: c, conditional-compilation, makefile

[enter link description here][1]I am writing this program which will enabled conditional compilation.

When the program is compiled in a standard way like this, it works fine without any error message:

```
gcc -Werror -Wall -pedantic -ansi -g -c display.c -o displayStack
```

But when I would like to compile with conditional compilation, I have an error message saying that there are implicit declaration of my functions in display.c

Here is how i compile it:

```
gcc -Werror -Wall -pedantic -ansi -g -c display.c -o displayStack -D STACK
```

Here is how I wrote the conditional command in the code:

```
#ifdef STACK
printLinkedList( stack );
#endif
```

Here is the `stack.h` file showing the include of `LinkedList.h` which has the function prototype for `printLinkedList`.

```
#ifndef STACK
#define STACK

#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList *createStack();
void push( LinkedList *, void * );
void *top( LinkedList * );
void *pop( LinkedList * );
void freeStack( LinkedList * );

#endif
```

May I know is there any issue over here? I cannot seem to find the problem because the first statement was working perfectly but when I have added "-D STACK" the program just show error message. Is it something wrong with my compiling command?

Error message I am receiving:

```
display.c: In function ‘display’:
display.c:21:5: error: unknown type name ‘LinkedList’
   21 |     LinkedList *stack = NULL;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
display.c:22:13: error: implicit declaration of function ‘createStack’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   22 |     stack = createStack();
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
display.c:22:11: error: assignment to ‘int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
   22 |     stack = createStack();
      |           ^
display.c:47:21: error: implicit declaration of function ‘push’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   47 |                     push( stack, bracket );
      |                     ^~~~
display.c:52:30: error: request for member ‘head’ in something not a structure or union
   52 |                     if( stack->head != NULL )
      |                              ^~
display.c:54:38: error: implicit declaration of function ‘top’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   54 |                         popBracket = top( stack );
      |                                      ^~~
display.c:54:36: error: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
   54 |                         popBracket = top( stack );
      |                                    ^
display.c:72:42: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pop’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   72 |                             popBracket = pop( stack );
      |                                          ^~~
display.c:72:40: error: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
   72 |                             popBracket = pop( stack );
      |                                        ^
display.c:108:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘printLinkedList’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  108 |                 printLinkedList( stack );
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
display.c:147:22: error: request for member ‘head’ in something not a structure or union
  147 |             if( stack->head == NULL )   /* Good case */
      |                      ^~
display.c:151:28: error: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
  151 |                 popBracket = top( stack );
      |                            ^
display.c:164:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘freeStack’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  164 |     freeStack( stack );
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
calmen@calmen:~/Desktop/Project/BracketCheck$ vim display.h
calmen@calmen:~/Desktop/Project/BracketCheck$ gcc -Werror -Wall -pedantic -ansi -g -c display.c -o displayStack -D STACK
display.c: In function ‘display’:
display.c:21:5: error: unknown type name ‘LinkedList’
   21 |     LinkedList *stack = NULL;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
display.c:22:13: error: implicit declaration of function ‘createStack’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   22 |     stack = createStack();
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
display.c:22:11: error: assignment to ‘int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
   22 |     stack = createStack();
      |           ^
display.c:47:21: error: implicit declaration of function ‘push’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   47 |                     push( stack, bracket );
      |                     ^~~~
display.c:52:30: error: request for member ‘head’ in something not a structure or union
   52 |                     if( stack->head != NULL )
      |                              ^~
display.c:54:38: error: implicit declaration of function ‘top’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   54 |                         popBracket = top( stack );
      |                                      ^~~
display.c:54:36: error: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
   54 |                         popBracket = top( stack );
      |                                    ^
display.c:72:42: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pop’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   72 |                             popBracket = pop( stack );
      |                                          ^~~
display.c:72:40: error: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
   72 |                             popBracket = pop( stack );
      |                                        ^
display.c:108:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘printLinkedList’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  108 |                 printLinkedList( stack );
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
display.c:147:22: error: request for member ‘head’ in something not a structure or union
  147 |             if( stack->head == NULL )   /* Good case */
      |                      ^~
display.c:151:28: error: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
  151 |                 popBracket = top( stack );
      |                            ^
display.c:164:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘freeStack’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  164 |     freeStack( stack );
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

The files can be find in the folder here.
[1]: https://github.com/Calmen00-code/BracketCheck

Comment: We can only guess without seeing your [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which you should provide. And also provide the **exact** error msgs. But it sound like there is no definition or prototype of the `printLinkedList` function before the point in the code that it is called at.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with conditional compilation per se.  It just means that the code that you enabled by adding `-DSTACK` has an error in it.  Without `-DSTACK` the code is ignored so the compiler didn't see any errors that were in it.  You don't show the actual error message (you should always cut/paste the actual error message when asking for help) but most likely it says that `printLinkedList` is the problem.  Search google for what the error "implicit declaration" means and how to fix it.

Comment: The code needs to be in the question as a minimal verifiable example and not as an external link. Anyway, I think we have given you fairly clear indication of what the likely error is. Do you understand what was said - functions need to be declared before they are called.

Comment: Hi, I have included the github link in the question. I have no clue why the implicit declaration is occurring as I have added my function declaration and it works fine without showing error message when I compiled it without conditional compilation. Hope I have made the question clear.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @kaylum. Yes I understand that function prototyping must comes before function definition. I have done so but it seems like it is still showing error message.

Comment: Please show the exact and full error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the include guard in the `stack.h` file:

```
#ifndef STACK
```

When you then define `STACK` on the command line that condition becomes FALSE and the header contents are not included. This results in missing prototypes in the C file.

To fix this you need to change either the C files or the header file to use a different preprocessor variable.

Comment: Yes, I have already used included STACK in stack.h. Changing it to something else like STACK_H will solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> gcc -Werror -Wall -pedantic -ansi -g -c display.c -o displayStack -D STACK

is strange. I would remove the space between `-D` and `STACK`

You might be interested by adding `-Wextra -fanalyze` to your `gcc` command. Read chapter about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html), section about [static analyzer options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html), and in end of 2020 consider upgrading to [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/).

Also, `-ansi` refers to an old C standard. Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then consider using `-std=c11`

When compiling your code `BracketCheck.tar.gz` (of md5sum `1b81b34f26db85fef69bda62a5bd4e63`) with `make CFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra -g -std=c11'` I am getting:

```
 display.c: In function ‘display’:
 display.c:21:5: error: unknown type name ‘LinkedList’
    21 |     LinkedList *stack = NULL;
       |     ^~~~~~~~~~
 display.c:22:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘createStack’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    22 |     stack = createStack();
       |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
 display.c:22:11: warning: assignment to ‘int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    22 |     stack = createStack();
       |           ^
 display.c:47:21: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘push’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    47 |                     push( stack, bracket );
       |                     ^~~~
 display.c:52:30: error: request for member ‘head’ in something not a structure or union
    52 |                     if( stack->head != NULL )
       |                              ^~
 display.c:54:38: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘top’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    54 |                         popBracket = top( stack );
       |                                      ^~~
 display.c:54:36: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    54 |                         popBracket = top( stack );
       |                                    ^
 display.c:72:42: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pop’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    72 |                             popBracket = pop( stack );
       |                                          ^~~
 display.c:72:40: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    72 |                             popBracket = pop( stack );
       |                                        ^
 display.c:108:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printLinkedList’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   108 |                 printLinkedList( stack );
       |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 display.c:147:22: error: request for member ‘head’ in something not a structure or union
   147 |             if( stack->head == NULL )   /* Good case */
       |                      ^~
 display.c:151:28: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   151 |                 popBracket = top( stack );
       |                            ^
 display.c:164:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘freeStack’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   164 |     freeStack( stack );
```

This is on Linux/x86-64/Ubuntu 20.04 with a [GCC 10.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/).

#### I recommend to fix your code till you get no warnings at all.

Adding `-DSTACK` don't fix all errors. Once they are all fixed use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program.

You could be interested by [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report and the [DECODER](http://decoder-project.eu/) and [CHARIOT](https://www.chariotproject.eu/) projects funding it.

You could also try using on your code [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

You might consider using [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) and/or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) and/or [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) and/or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) to generate some of your code (in C, or your `makefile` ...) using [meta-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) techniques after reading the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools).

Comment: The `-D` option takes an argument which may be attached or detached from the flag.  Ditto `-l` and `-L` and `-I` (and `-U`, and …).  Granted, it is aconventional to place a space between the option and the argument, but it is valid to do so.  Interestingly, GCC does not accept a space between `-W` and `vla` (or between `-f` and `analyze`) — and probably doesn't for some other options too, therefore.  So it is certainly simpler and normal to leave the space out.